# Generate own pages based on USER ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I can't think of a better title for this query of mine. I am trying to display all users and then have a VIEW link in each rows (based on their user id) .. for like example: `http://minquep.com/pages/23` (Wherein 23 is the user id of one user)...

Here's my display function with delete function too.

I already displayed the VIEW link in each rows using

```
<a href="<? echo $rows['user_id']?>VIEW</a>
```

My problem is that, each url's of VIEW link are not yet generated under pages folder.

How can make a view.php in each user based on their user_ids

Is it possible when I add a user, an automatic view page will be created. and How can I call that in my display function

```
<!-- ALL MEMBERS QUERY -->
        <div id="allmembers" class="content">
            <?php
                include("connection.php"); #DATABASE CONNECTION DO NOT EDIT

                #Moderators
                $sql="SELECT user_id, special_id, login, user_type, company FROM $tbl_name";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);

                #count all mods
                $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
            ?>

        <br style="clear:both;">

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:1%;">
            <?php echo "<font size='3px'>There are $count users:</font>"; #OUTPUT COUNT MODS ?>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return confirm('Click OK or Cancel to Continue');">
            <table width="100%" border="1%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">#</td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>User Type</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Company</strong></td>
                </tr>

        <?php
            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['special_id']; ?>"></td>
                    <td width="10%"><? echo $rows['special_id']; ?></td>
                    <td width="25%"><? echo $rows['login']; ?></td>
                    <td width="20%"><? echo $rows['user_type']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $rows['company']; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?echo $rows['user_id']; ?>">View</a></td>
                </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>

                <tr>
                    <td width="10%" border="0"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete Selected User(s)"></td>
                </tr>



            </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
                // Check if delete button active, start this 
                if($_POST['delete']){
                $checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];
                for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
                $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
                $sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE special_id='$del_id'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);}
                // if successful redirect back to manage_users.php
                if($result){
                echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=manage_users.php\">"; #REDIRECTION ITSELF
                }
                }

            ?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html). Creating a physical page for each user would be madness.

Basically, by default, you'd have a URL like this: **http://minquep.com/page.php?user_id=3323**

Using URL rewriting, you can allow people to access the profile.php page via a URL such as: **http://minquep.com/pages/3323**

Comment: URL rewriting has a documentation in PHP itself?

Comment: @xirukitepe No, but you can read up about it here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: So if I rewrite urls... will I generate their own pages from there? Thanks.

Comment: If you rewrite the URLs, you won't need to generate pages. Do a few of the beginner examples and you'll quickly see what I'm talking about.

Comment: +1, additional comment to the OP: If you are just getting started with PHP i'd recommend maybe starting with using urls like `http://minquep.com/page.php?user_id=3323` then in your script you can access the id via the global `$_GET` array. i.e. `$id = $_GET['user_id']`. Read about passing parameters to a web page via GET (and POST in some cases)

Comment: @KennyCason I get it. You mean I should transform my link into `<a href="view.php?<?echo $rows['user_id']; ?>">View</a>` and then in view.php I should use `$GET` function?

Comment: @xirukitepe Your link should be `<a href="view.php?user_id=<?echo $rows['user_id']; ?>">View</a>` and then you can access the id from within view.php using `$_GET['user_id']`

Comment: @xirukitepe Exactly. with the minor edit that Nick mentioned.

Comment: Okay. is it possible also that in specific url like `http://minquep.com/view.php?user_id=3323` i can also display the query (other info) about the user who has an id of 3323? THANKS.